# Electron - Why set BrowserWindow instance to null on the close event

Tags: javascript, electron

The [electron documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window), provides the following code sample to create a new window:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
});

win.loadURL('https://github.com');
```

**My question is:** why set win to null at the close event?

**N.B.** The [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow) class inherits from class [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).
I am not sure if this information is relevant, but I thought it might help to include it in the question.

Please give a detailed explanation with your answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not mandatory, but a good coding practice (in every language).

[Docs of 'closed'](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-closed) mentions it in a little bit more details:

> After you have received this event you should remove the reference to
>   the window and avoid using it any more.

That is, when you destroy an object prefer setting it to an invalid value for avoiding function calls on a flawed/un-complete object.

Consider this example:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = null
app.once('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
  setInterval(() => {
    if (win) win.loadURL('http://google.com')
    else app.quit()
  }, 3000)
  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {})
})
```

The proper `'closed'` callback here helps to avoid future calls on destroyed object.

---

For electron's `BrowserWindow` you can use `isDestroyed()` method as well, which potentially makes the use of `'closed'` unnecessary but invalidating objects is a general technique while destroy queries are always up to the API.