# Why set a variable to null right before returning from a function?

Tags: javascript, electron

While reading a book on electron, I stumbled upon the following code.

```js
const windows = new Set();

app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow();
});


const createWindow = exports.createWindow = () => {

  let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false
  });

  newWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));

  newWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    newWindow.show();
  });

  newWindow.on('closed', () => {
    windows.delete(newWindow);
    newWindow = null;
  });

  windows.add(newWindow);
  return newWindow;
};
```

This is what I think is happening, the variable `newWindow` is local to the function. The `closed event` is the last event to occur. Thus when the `closed event` is finished the function ends. meaning the `newWindow` variable no longer exist.

Based on my present understanding, I don't see the point of setting `newWindow` to null right before the function ends.

Is there any reason for doing so?

```
  newWindow.on('closed', () => {
    windows.delete(newWindow);
    newWindow = null;
  });
```

Comment: This is essentially a dispose of the object to destroy the object completely freeing the memory.

Comment: @ abc123 wont that happened automatically when the function ends, since the  life of the variable dies?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527312/2550156 as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't see the point of setting `newWindow` to `null` right before
>   the function ends.

That code doesn't set `newWindow` to `null` *right before the function ends*. It sets it when the `window` gets closed **(which will be sometime in the future)** and therefore `newWindow` will persist in memory until that time.

The `.on` callback uses the `newWindow` variable, which is declared in a higher scope, thereby setting up a **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** around it. **This means that `newWindow` will persist after the function that it is declared in (the arrow function assigned to `exports.createWindow`) ends.**

To prevent the variable from persisting indefinitely, the assignment to `null` is there to ensure that the memory is released when the `window` that was using it is closed.

Comment: Thanks you. That  clears things up :). Can't accept answer yet though.